# Configure Nginx-ingress with 'client_header_buffer_size' without server-snippet

Tags: nginx, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, ingress-controller

I understand that Nginx-ingress from 1.9, by default, disables use of server-snippet because of the security risks it includes. See: [CVE-2021-25742](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2021-25742).

For that reason, I believe it is best to get rid of all use of 'nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet' in all ingresses.
But I would like to `client_header_buffer_size` and `large_client_header_buffers`. Is it possible to do differently than:

```
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
        client_header_buffer_size 20k;
        large_client_header_buffers 4 20k;
```

It can be done using [Nginx's own ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/#client-header-buffer-size) but then it applies for all ingresses. I believe it isn't the case when I use server-snippet, or am I wrong?

Increase the max header size without using server-snippet as it adds security risks.